# JSP compile error ANT to Maven conversion

Tags: java, jsp, maven, ant

I have a project that I am migrating from ANT to Maven. The ANT project successfully deployees and runs. However, I am getting the following JSP compile error when I try to run the mavenized project:

```
11:16:00,842 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ntsouthwest].[jsp]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 411 in the jsp file: /pages/includes/required_fields_incl.jsp
ITEM_STATUS_DISPOSED_LOCALLY cannot be resolved or is not a field
408:        currentElementName=currentElement.name;
409:        if (currentElementName.indexOf("disposal_status.status_ID") != -1) {
410:            var disposeStatus=currentElement.options[currentElement.selectedIndex].value;
411:            if(disposeStatus!="" && disposeStatus==<%=TracingConstants.ITEM_STATUS_DISPOSED_LOCALLY%>){
412:                if(disposeLocal!=false){
413:                    alert("<%=(String) bundle
414:                            .getString( "disposal.remark")%>" + " <%=(String) bundle.getString(


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:446) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:607) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:657) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.dynamic.sessionjs_jsp._jspService(sessionjs_jsp.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
```

I have verified that the class exists in the war and that the attribute also exists.

Comment: Make sure `TracingConstants` class exists in the dependency libraries for the war project or in your war project. Also, if you can, [**stop using scriptlets at all**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197).

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. Do I need to add this to the dependency section of the manifest?

Comment: In maven, you have a `<dependencies>` section in your pom.xml file. There, you should provide all the external libraries for your project. In one of those libraries, `TracingConstants` should be defined. Make sure you have the necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You have an old version of TracingConstants (without the constant) in an LFC jar which you put in Artifactory and established a dependency upon. The new version of TracingConstants (with the constant) is in the ntcore jar. Runtime is using the LFC version rather than the ntcore version.

Sincerely,

A current employee of your former employer.